# Can't install sinatra-contrib

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I am trying to run a simple application with Sinatra and I am not able to install the reloader.

I tried with

```
gem install sinatra-contrib
```

and I have in my source file a line like this:

```
require "sinatra/reloader" if development?
```

and in my `Gemfile`

```
gem "sinatra-contrib", "~> "1.3.1"
gem 'sinatra-reloader'
```

and I get an error while trying to start the gem install sinatra-config

```
>gem install sinatra-contrib

ERROR:  Error installing sinatra-contrib:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.`
```

I can't figure it out. And if I have the `require "sinatra/reloader" if development?` line, it just won't work. There are not many things on the web about this. I know shotgun is not an option in Windows.

Comment: Do you mean `sinatra-contrib` when you say `sinatra-config`? There is no `sinatra-config` gem on rubygems.org. Also `sinatra-contrib` doesn’t include any native extensions, so the error message must be coming fom something else.

Comment: is your problem solved? then please accept the best answer. If not, tell us more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [shotgun](http://ruby.about.com/od/sinatra/a/sinatra5.htm)(A Sinatra code reloader)? I used that to reload sinatra code when I was using Windows as my primary machine

Comment: Everywhere I've looked I've seen that Shotgun doesn't work on windows. May you tell me how you installed it?

Comment: I get this standard error like everyone else does on windows:
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/shotgun-0.9/bin/shotgun:142:in `trap': unsupported signal SIGQUIT (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error once. [Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/1371843), check the comments under that. Basically, `sinatra-contrib` depends on `event machine` which is not good for Windows. Remove that dependency or install `event machine`

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Sinatra reloader doesn't compile under Windows. You must install version 0.5 :

```
gem install sinatra-reloader -v 0.5.0
```